# Symfony 2 - Encode string to be used as URL

Tags: url, symfony, encoding

Dose Symfony 2 have a method like Wordpress's [`sanitize_title_with_dashes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes) or Codeigniter's [`url_title`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) that converts strings like `____I    am Bob` to `i-am-bob`?

Comment: something like preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g', '', $input) and preg_replace('/\s/g', '-', $input) and strtolower($input)?

Comment: Yeah, but the mentioned functions do a bit more, like proper UTF-8 sanitisation.

Comment: maybe this will work http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the DoctrineExtension Sluggable with the StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.

Find the documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html) and example [here](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md#basic-usage-examples).